# Upgrading a Pre-Built Mini PC

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer

A few years ago, I won an HP Mini PC as a door prize at an event I went to. I have tried using it to play video games, but it isn't strong enough to run them. I am wondering if there is any way to upgrade it without buying all new components? I do want to upgrade the graphics mostly. It has an Intel HD Graphics 4600 card.

This is the computer for specific details:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-prodesk-600-g1-desktop-mini-pc/6595197/model/6595201?sku=K1K25UT

Comment: Would you be able to find what graphics card is currently in the machine? it looks like that model could come with an AMD or two other NVIDIA graphics cards.

Comment: @PloxPanda The computer has an "Intel i5 inside" sticker on it and the Direct X Diagnostic Tool on my computer says it's an Intel HD Graphics 4600

Comment: That PC could have an optional Nvidia NVS 310, I doubt you can go any better due to the PSU limitations.>>>>https://www.amazon.com/PNY-DisplayPort-Multi-Display-Professional-VCNVS310DP-PB/dp/B008B6ONWQ

Comment: @Moab Are yu sure a miniPC like this supports an add-on card? Even the one you posted looks larger than the miniPC...

Comment: @Moab Okay, so is the Nvidia NVS 310 better than the Intel 4600? Can I also increase the PSU if possible? I wouldn't mind buying a new case.

Comment: Just confirmed in the service manual. **The only upgrades possible, within specifications, are CPU, RAM and storage (SATA)** The graphics are CPU embedded so upgrading the CPU may or may not upgrade the graphics.

Comment: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04327174.pdf

Comment: @ChanganAuto Awww, Man. Well, thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: The best it can go is a Intel Core i7 4785T which has the exact same graphics your i5 has. And max RAM is 8GB, that's all you can do.